# VSTO Document-Level customization deployment of 2 environments in one box

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, clickonce

this is my scenario, i have a Excel VSTO Document-Level customization which i need to install two different versions in one box(QA version and Development version), i am using ClickOnce strategy to achieve this scenario and it works fine i am deploying the application to development file share, and after that i change the assembly name and product name just adding the word QA, and i deploy the application again, into QA server. So the user is able to install both application but seems they are conflicting when the customization opens it only able to get the settings from only one of the environments, depends on which of those was installed latest, such a weird behavior, even if i open for example the development customization it is pointing to QA file share server, has anyone faced the same? Or had accomplished this scenario in a other way

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple deployments for this purpose and as far as I can tell, the main thing that needs to be changed is the SolutionID in the *.csproj file (generate a new value using Tools > Create GUID). As long as you change that, the rest of the fields don't really matter.

This means you need two copies of the *.csproj file, and two  *.sln files, to point to the right *.csproj, if you use those.